# Return a list of rotational equivalence pairs from a given string in scala

Tags: scala

Input String

> ["ac","bd","ce", "aaa","xyz","bbb","abc","kt","zb"]

I want the below output:

> [List("ac","bd","ce","zb"),List("aaa","bbb"),List("abc","xyz"),List("kt")]

The logic here is I need to group similar elements into Lists.

The pattern in the first list is, I have one letter skipped.

The pattern in the second list is, I have one letter repeating thrice.

The pattern in the third list is, I have 3 consecutive letters.

After grouping all of this, I have one element which does not fall into any of the above patterns hence adding it to a seperate list.

I am not sure of the algorithm/solution in scala. Any help is appreciated. TIA.

Comment: `"zb"` has one letter skipped?

Comment: Yes letter 'a' is skipped

Comment: Are you asking for a solution to that specific logic, or a more general grouping by rotational equivalence? If you are looking for a general solution you need to specify more clearly what you mean by "similar". For example, would `ku` be in the same group as `kt`? Would `ab` be in the same group as `abc`?

Comment: I am looking for a generic solution. `ku` and `kt` cannot be in the same group because distance of `kt` is not equal to `ku`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods that constructs the rotation equivalence representation of Strings.

```
  def normalizedRepresentation(str: String) = {
    str.map(char => (char - str.charAt(0) + 'a').asInstanceOf[Char])
  }

  def rotationalEquivalenceRepresentation(str: String) = {
    val normalizedStr = normalizedRepresentation(str)
    normalizedStr.map(char => if (char < 'a') (char + 26).asInstanceOf[Char] else char.asInstanceOf[Char])
  }
```

then

```
scala>   val input = List("ac","bd","ce", "aaa","xyz","bbb","abc","kt","zb")
input: List[String] = List(ac, bd, ce, aaa, xyz, bbb, abc, kt, zb)

scala>   input.map(str => normalizedRepresentation(str))
res0: List[String] = List(ac, ac, ac, aaa, abc, aaa, abc, aj, aI)

scala>   input.map(str => rotationalEquivalenceRepresentation(str))
res1: List[String] = List(ac, ac, ac, aaa, abc, aaa, abc, aj, ac)

scala> 

scala>   input.groupBy(str => rotationalEquivalenceRepresentation(str))
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[String]] = Map(abc -> List(xyz, abc), aaa -> List(aaa, bbb), ac -> List(ac, bd, ce, zb), aj -> List(kt))

scala>   input.groupBy(str => rotationalEquivalenceRepresentation(str)).values.toList
res3: List[List[String]] = List(List(xyz, abc), List(aaa, bbb), List(ac, bd, ce, zb), List(kt))
```

Comment: Thank you. How did you arrive at this? Is this based on any algorithm?

Comment: Use `toChar` rather than `asInstanceOf[Char]`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a rather pointless exercise.

```
val input = List("ac","bd","ce", "aaa","xyz","bbb","abc","kt","zb")

val (skip1, rest1) =
  input.partition(s => s.length == 2 && s(1)-s(0) == 2 || s(0)-s(1) == 24)
//skip1: List[String] = List(ac, bd, ce, zb)
//rest1: List[String] = List(aaa, xyz, bbb, abc, kt)

val (same3, rest2) =
  rest1.partition(s => s.length == 3 && s.forall(_ == s(0)))
//same3: List[String] = List(aaa, bbb)
//rest2: List[String] = List(xyz, abc, kt)

val (seq3, rest3) =
  rest2.partition(s => s.length == 3 && s(1)-s(0) == 1 && s(2)-s(1) == 1)
//seq3: List[String] = List(xyz, abc)
//rest3: List[String] = List(kt)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic solution to the question.

```
def rotationGroup(s: String) =
  s.sliding(2).toList.map(s => ('a' + s(1) - s(0)) % 26)

list.groupBy(rotationGroup).values
```

It works by computing the distance between a pair of letters and then representing the "rotation group" as a list of distances between each adjacent pairs in the string.

This is an annotated version of the function with error checking:

```
def rotationGroup(s: String) =
  s
    .sliding(2) // Group letters into pairs
    .filter(_.length > 1) // Avoid strings with 0 or 1 letters
    .map(s => ('a' + s(1) - s(0)) % 26) // Compute modulo distance between letters
    .toList // Convert from an iterator to a concrete list
```

Comment: the annotated version contains filter

Comment: @MikhailIonkin Yes, that is the error checking. I left it out of the original for simplicity. Without this the solution would fail if there were fewer than 2 letters in a string.